# Dynamics 365 Plugin An error occurred in FollowUpPlugin 0x80040265

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven, dynamics-365-sales

I have a plugin that is executed when a new instance from the sales order detail entity is created. when creating the instance an error appears in the plugin trace log:

```
get Ref
productIdRef 
de_prdrate: 19
de_salesprdrate: 19

System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]: The product and the unit cannot be updated while the entity is locked. (Fault Detail is equal to Exception details:
ErrorCode: 0x80040265
Message: The product and the unit cannot be updated while the entity is locked.
 OriginalException: PluginExecution ExceptionSource: PluginExecution
```

> Note:
> there is also a System workflow running on the sales order detail entity on the create event.
> the plugin works fine on the quote details entity without any exceptions or errors.

I think the problem is that my plugin and the system workflow work on the same event. I did not find any solution to this problem. I appreciate any suggestions.

The code is below:

```cs
public class Update_Salesdetails_Field : IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

            try
            {
                if (entity.LogicalName != "salesorderdetail")
                {
                    tracingService.Trace("Target entity is not Sales Order Detail! plug-in was not registered correctly! Exit PlugIn", serviceProvider);
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("The current entity is not the Sales Order Detail entity");
                }

                tracingService.Trace("get Ref", serviceProvider);
                var productIdRef = entity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("productid");

                tracingService.Trace("productIdRef", serviceProvider);
                var productEntity = service.Retrieve("product", productIdRef.Id, new ColumnSet("de_prdrate"));

                tracingService.Trace("de_prdrate: " + productEntity["de_prdrate"]);
                entity["de_salesprdrate"] = productEntity["de_prdrate"];

                tracingService.Trace("de_salesprdrate " + entity["de_salesprdrate"]);
                service.Update(entity);

                tracingService.Trace("Update salesprdrate " + entity["de_salesprdrate"]);
            }
            catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
            {
                tracingService.Trace("exception:", ex.ToString());
                tracingService.Trace(ex.StackTrace);

                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    tracingService.Trace("inner exception:", ex.InnerException.ToString());
                    tracingService.Trace(ex.InnerException.StackTrace);
                }

                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tracingService.Trace("FollowUpPlugin: {0}", ex.ToString());
                tracingService.Trace(ex.StackTrace);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without any code or stack trace it is hard to tell what went wrong. You should be able to add some exception handling to your plugin code and write the stack trace of the exception thrown to `ITracingService`, along with its inner exceptions.

Comment: Thanks @HenkvanBoeijen for your comment, I added my code and the trace log to my question.

Comment: In its current state your plugin does not trace anything. It rethrows the exception immediately. I modified your code sample.

Comment: thanks @HenkvanBoeijen thanks for your help, but the trace did not the trace log  still the same. I have changed the catch block and the error appears as follows :  The product and the unit cannot be updated while the entity is locked.

Comment: In which stage and mode does the plugin execute and what is the `salesorderdetail.statecode` of the entity?

Comment: Execution stage : PostOperation , Execution mode : Synchronous. But the salesorderdetail.statecode  I couldn't find its value.

Comment: Statement `service.Update(entity)` causes the exception. Remove that line and register your plugin on a pre stage. Please, refer to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the post operation stage of the plugin pipeline for message "Update" the system blocks modifications to the `entity` object that is subject of the plugin pipeline. (This is the entity that was retrieved from tne `context.InputParameters` collection.)

Instead the plugin should be registered on the pre validation or pre operation stage. In these plugin pipeline stages attributes can be modified on entity found in `context.InputParameters["Target"]`.

The entity object must not be updated explicitly, so **remove** this line:

```cs
service.Update(entity);
```